# Compojure Ring Server Generated By 'lein ring server' Acting Oddly

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

So I was coding and I got an exception. I fixed the exception and then went back to check that things were working. Instead of seeing my fixes I instead saw the website that was generated prior to the exception having been thrown. Like my previous code had been cached and now it was being used. I double checked this intuition by commenting everything out and trying to put in a string instead of the web page and this still resulted in no changes to my site. So I went ahead and tried restarting the server. This didn't fix things. So then I tried running lein clean. This didn't fix things either. What the hell is going on here and how do I fix it?

I'm pretty sure my code is irrelevant, because I'm getting the same problem no matter what code I use. For those that are wondering the initial exception was that the function clojure.string/replace was already being used at clojure.core/replace or in other words I had a naming conflict. I resolved this by (:require [clojure.string :as string]).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another server running?

Comment: `netstat -npl | grep 8080`

Comment: Can't really say as the problem went away upon a system restart prior to having seen your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, so I ended up restarting my computer and the problem was solved. The actual reason I had this problem I'm not so sure of.